# Can a column in a composite key be a foreign key to another table?

Tags: sql-server

Can a column in a composite key be a foreign key to another table?
If no then how to connect two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's one major benefit of using composite keys. This is one way to break apart a Many-to-Many relationship.